# If I am querying below query, getting error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Exec('select * from dual ' );
```

Showing invalid Sql query. Is it a valid query? If no, what could the reason and solution?

Comment: Exec is used to execute a function or stored proc, not for running a select statement. You probably want to use Execute Immediate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375990/oracle-what-does-execute-immediate-mean

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC` is a SQL*Plus command, used to run PL/SQL code (usually procedures).

But, if you insist on selecting from dual, no problem. Here's how: as it has to be PL/SQL, declare a variable and select into it. As `DUAL` has one column (named `DUMMY`), it'll work just fine:

```
SQL> var l_dum varchar2;
SQL> exec select * into :l_dum from dual;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_dum

L_DUM
--------------------------------
X

SQL>
```

---

What we *normally* do is

```
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

---

Your error? Single quotes, no variable to select into.

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC[UTE] IMMEDIATE` must be used within an anonymous block or procedure.

For example:

```
 Begin

 Execute Immediate 'Select * From Dual';

 End;
```

Here is a simple Youtube explanation:
https://youtu.be/47KzYVBNbIs